# Finding the transformation matrix that reflects a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

Given the transformation expression: $\;\;\boldsymbol A\cdot\,\boldsymbol b\ = \boldsymbol b - 2(\boldsymbol b\,\cdot\,\hat{\boldsymbol n})\hat{\boldsymbol n}\;\;\text{where}\; \boldsymbol A\cdot\,\boldsymbol b$ is the reflected vector of $\boldsymbol b$ from the reflection plane and $\hat{\boldsymbol n}$ is the unit vector normal to the reflection plane.

How do I get the transformation matrix $\boldsymbol A\;$ if for example, the unit vector $\hat{\boldsymbol n}$ is expressed as $2(\hat{\boldsymbol i} + \hat{\boldsymbol j} + \hat{\boldsymbol k} )$

I have tried expressing $\boldsymbol b$ in terms of it's components $b_{1}\hat{\boldsymbol i} + b_{2}\hat{\boldsymbol j}+b_3\hat{\boldsymbol k}\;$ but I get stuck when I open up the term $\;(\boldsymbol b\,\cdot\,\hat{\boldsymbol n})\hat{\boldsymbol n}\;$ as $\frac{ (b_{1}\hat{\boldsymbol i} + b_{2}\hat{\boldsymbol j}+b_3\hat{\boldsymbol k})\,\cdot 2(\hat{\boldsymbol i} + \hat{\boldsymbol j} + \hat{\boldsymbol k})}{12} \cdot 2(\hat{\boldsymbol i} + \hat{\boldsymbol j} + \hat{\boldsymbol k} )$

Comment: Simply put the coordinates of $Ai,\, Aj,\, Ak$ into columns. Note that the given $n$ is *not* a unit vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the transformation expression 
$$\boldsymbol A\cdot\,\boldsymbol b\ = \boldsymbol b - 2(\boldsymbol b\,\cdot\,\hat{\boldsymbol n})\hat{\boldsymbol n}$$

One can simply derive that:

$$\boldsymbol A = \boldsymbol I - 2 \, \hat{\boldsymbol n}\,\hat{\boldsymbol n}^T$$

where $\boldsymbol I$ is the identity matrix

If, for example,

$$ \hat{\boldsymbol n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}(\hat{\boldsymbol i} + \hat{\boldsymbol j} + \hat{\boldsymbol k} )$$

Then

$$\boldsymbol{A}_{i,j} = \delta(i-j) - \frac{2}{3}$$